# mysql query only works when value is compared with primary key

Tags: mysql, select, where

I'm working with this table:

```
mysql> describe dispositivos;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sn        | varchar(25) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| device_id | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ip_adress | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've noticed that when I type a query like this:

```
mysql> select * from dispositivos WHERE sn = "SAL1027TVGH";
+-------------+---------------+------------------+
| sn          | device_id     | ip_adress        |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+
| SAL1027TVGH |  CU_DGIE_6509 |  148.228.110.254 |
+-------------+---------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

everything goes fine, but if I search by any other field, the query is not working.

```
mysql> select * from dispositivos WHERE ip_adress ="148.228.110.254";
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from dispositivos WHERE device_id ="CU_DGIE_6509";
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Do you know why this is happening?

there are other tables, but the problem just affect this one, it is being filled automatically with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

thanks.

Comment: Judging by the alignment of your column names and data, it looks like you have a space at the start of both fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the output of your select statement: it seems you have a leading blank in your values.